# Get the percentage of the discount value in c#

Tags: c#

In my applicattion i want to find how much in percent is the discount, 
I have the price of an item then when i give a new price and find the Subtraction I want to know how much is that in percent,
example:

```
decimal realPrice = 1800;
decimal newPrice = 1700;
decimal difference = realPrice - newPrice; // = 100
decimal discountPercent = ????;
```

How many percent is this diffence as a discount in percent from the realprice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://nb.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-basics/core-algebra-foundations/algebra-foundations-decimal-operations/e/percentage_word_problems_1 Khan academy is a great place to learn basic mathematics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sJioJC)

```
decimal discountPercent = (difference / realPrice) * 100;
Console.WriteLine("Discount Percentage : {0}%",discountPercent.ToString("#.##"));
```

Little [maths](http://www.math-only-math.com/calculating-profit-percent-and-loss-percent.html) for explanation:

Answer (score 3):

You should divide difference by realPrice and then multiply it by 100 to get percentages

```
decimal discountPercent = difference / realPrice * 100;
```

It should give you `5.(5)%`

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal discountPercent = difference / realPrice * 100;
```

Though this is not a programming question, but rather math question for middle school. :D